# How to convert a mysql json field to a javascript Object with laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using laravel with eloquent and a mysql database.

There is a JSON field in my database:

```
class CreateJogoDetalhesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tableX', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            [... others ...]
            $table->json('numbers');
    }
[...]
```

When I retrieve the data on my model/api route:

```
Route::middleware('cors:api')->get('/MYROUTE', function (Request $request) {
    $resource= Tablex::with('tb1','tb2','tb3')->get();
    return $resource->toJson();
});
```

My mysql json field comes with a string format:

```
tableX": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "foo",
      "values": "{\"6\": 3.5, \"7\": 24.5, \"8\": 24.5, \"9\": 24.5, \"10\": 24.5, \"11\": 24.5, \"12\": 24.5, \"13\": 24.5, \"14\": 24.5, \"15\": 24.5}",
    },
```

But I need them on this format:

```
"tableX": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "foo",
      "values": {
        "6": 3.5,
        "7": 24.5,
        "8": 24.5,
        "9": 24.5,
        "10": 24.5,
        "11": 24.5,
        "12": 24.5,
        "13": 24.5,
        "14": 24.5,
        "15": 24.5
      },
```

How can I ask to laravel catch the data on this format?

Comment: Read the manual for `json_decode()`

Comment: Although you may have stored that data incorrectly as it is not a valid json string

Comment: I know the json_decode function. But this is a pure php solution. I want a solution that use laravel/eloquent to solve the string json problem.

Comment: `json_decode()` is PURE PHP

Comment: It is a valid json. The json type in mysql do all json validation before accept the data.

Comment: Yes!, it is PURE PHP (native on), but how conveter the json field using the Laravel/Eloquent?

Comment: Thanks for all help guys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The array cast type is particularly useful when working with columns
>   that are stored as serialized JSON. For example, if your database has
>   a JSON or TEXT field type that contains serialized JSON, adding the
>   array cast to that attribute will automatically deserialize the
>   attribute to a PHP array when you access it on your Eloquent model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'values' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

This will convert it to an array on the PHP side and will properly include the JSON data when Laravel serializes the model.

Comment: Ohh man! Array & JSON Casting that is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you!